# IsolatedStorageException in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, stack-trace, isolatedstorage

I received a stack trace report which says there is an IsolatedStorageException.

"Frame    Image             Function                                                  Offset
0        coredll.dll       xxx_RaiseException
1        mscoree3_7.dll
2        mscoree3_7.dll
3        mscoree3_7.dll
4                          TransitionStub
5                          System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.Save
6                          System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.Clear
7                          AppName.CycleManager.WriteToIsolatedStorage
8                          AppName.SettingsPage.OnNavigatedFrom
9                          Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.InternalOnNavigatedFrom
10                  System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.RaiseNavigated
11                  System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.CompleteNavigation 
12                  System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.ContentLoader_BeginLoad_Callback
13                  System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.BeginLoad_OnUIThread 
14                  ._*c*_DisplayClass4._BeginLoad_b__0
15       mscoree3_7.dll
16       mscoree3_7.dll
17       mscoree3_7.dll
18                         System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke 
19                         System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke  "

So I presume it the exception is raised by the WriteToIsolatedStorage().

```
public void WriteToIsolatedStorage()
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings dataStorage = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        dataStorage.Clear();


        dataStorage.Add("firstLaunchDate", App.LaunchedDateTime);

        dataStorage.Add("weekStart", m_bWeekStart);

        dataStorage.Add("iHistCount", m_iHistCount);

        // All the variables i need to store

        dataStorage.Add("noteCount", m_noteCount);

        WriteNotesToFile();

        dataStorage.Add("weightCount", m_iWeightCount);

        WriteWeightToFile();

        dataStorage.Add("tempCount", m_iTempCount);

        WriteTempToFile();

        dataStorage.Save();
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

```
    public void WriteNotesToFile()
    {
        if (m_noteCount > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFile storagefile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (storagefile.FileExists("NotesFile"))
                    {
                        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = storagefile.OpenFile("NotesFile", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                        {
                            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

                            for (int i = 0; i < m_noteCount; i++)
                            {
                                //writer.Write(m_arrNoteDate[i].ToShortDateString());
                                writer.Write(m_arrNoteDate[i].ToString("d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                                writer.Write(" ");
                                writer.Write(m_arrNoteString[i]);
                                writer.WriteLine("~`");
                            }
                            writer.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        storagefile.CreateFile("NotesFile.txt");
                        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = storagefile.OpenFile("NotesFile", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                        {
                            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

                            for (int i = 0; i < m_noteCount; i++)
                            {
                                //writer.Write(m_arrNoteDate[i].ToShortDateString());
                                writer.Write(m_arrNoteDate[i].ToString("d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                                writer.Write(" ");
                                writer.Write(m_arrNoteString[i]);
                                writer.WriteLine("~`");
                            }
                            writer.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

Could anyone tell me in which condition the Exception is thrown. I read somewhere that when there is not enough of space, such exception will be thrown.

Lastly, I have 4 isolated storage files to which i write values.Does the following method remove all 4 of them?

```
IsolatedStorageFile storagefile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
storagefile.Remove();
```

I would be really grateful if someone could clarify these.

Thank you,

Comment: Hi, can you provide the exception message ?

Comment: @Ashura The funny thing is im not able to reproduce the crash. :( I dont know what message is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to [`Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.save%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) would fail if there wasn't enough space.
As we can't see what the `WriteXxxxToFile()` methods are doing, they could be doing something which could cause this issue.

It could also be tied to issues where you have multiple threads trying to access the settings or the app closing or tombstoning but your save method taking too long.

Your best bet for identifying the true cause would be to add some handling to support the scenario where a call to `WriteToIsolatedStorage()` raises such an exception and then log and report it as is appropriate to your app/needs.

Regarding `Remove`, as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay840d1%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

> "This method irrevocably removes the entire isolated storage for the
>   current users's application and all its directories and files."

Comment: Thanks @Matt, I have updated the question with the WriteNoteToFile function. This report came only came after i updated the version with few changes. It never used to come before that. Strangely for the update the logic for the write/read was never modified.

Comment: In that you'er suppressing any error from the `WriteNoteToFile` method it won't be there. I suggest adding appropriate error logging and exception handling and submitting an update.